# Jquery chaining animation with each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making an animation with every item element inside the list. My goal is when each item finish the animate function, the next item start to animate and so on. Right now, all i did is all the items run animate function at the same time. The list of item should have hundred of items, i just demonstrate 3 items.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.list-item').each(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        _this.find(".loading").animate({
            width: "100%"
        }, 2500);
    });
})
```

```css
.list-item .item {
  position: relative;
  }
  .list-item .item {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .list-item .item .loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    opacity: 0.3;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="item">
        Item 1
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 2
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 3
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using **promise**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var queue = $.Deferred().resolve(); 
      $('.list-item').find(".loading").each(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        queue = queue.then(function(){
           return _this.animate({width: "100%"}, 2500).promise();
        })
    });
  });
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/dKqOja

Comment: What if i want to do more than just animate, e.g: display something in that item element during animation and after animation?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setTimeout()` with a dynamique `delay` to achieve that

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var delay = 0;
  $('.list-item .loading').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.animate({
        width: "100%"
      }, 2500);
    }, delay)
    delay += 2500;


  });
})
```

```css
.list-item .item {
  position: relative;
}

.list-item .item {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.list-item .item .loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
    <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
    <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
    <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [complete callback-function of the animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to run the next loading sequence:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var animate = function($this) {            
        $this.find(".loading").animate({
            width: "100%"
        }, 2500, 
         function() {
           var $next = $this.next();
           if ($next.length > 0) {
               animate($next);
           }
         });
       };

      animate($('.item').first());
     
})
```

```css
.list-item .item {
  position: relative;
  }
  .list-item .item {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .list-item .item .loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    opacity: 0.3;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="item">
        Item 1
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 2
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 3
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have exact number of items to animate and defined delay - you can set `setTimout` to call each animation in exact time (when previous already completed)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.item').each(function(i){
        setTimeout(function() { $(this).find(".loading").animate({ width: "100%" }, 2500); }.bind(this), i * 2500);
    });
})
```

```css
.list-item .item {
  position: relative;
  }
  .list-item .item {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .list-item .item .loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    opacity: 0.3;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="item">
        Item 1
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 2
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Item 3
        <span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```